# canvas работа со списком объектов

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Мне нужно реализовать список из объектов canvas, в которомый при добавлении или удалении объекта из списка, в окне объекты сдвигались.
Я написал добавление элемента в список, но дальше у меня ступор.
Во-первых, у меня добавляется элемент в список, но в окне он сдвигается просто (пересоздаваясь на новых координатах)
Во-вторых, я понять не могу как мне например из списка удалить именно второй элемент, в последующем например третьий (ведь после первого удаления он по логики должен стать вторым), то есть нужно ориентироваться как-то по именам желательно.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

list = []
pos = 1
image = None

class test(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.bb = Button(self.canvas, text='OK', command=self.ski)
        self.bb.place(x=800/2, y=600/2)
        self.bc = Button(self.canvas, text='Del', command=self.ski2)
        self.bc.place(x=800/2, y=600/2)

    def ski(self):
        global pos, image
        self.img = Image.open('test.png'))
        self.img = self.img.resize((32, 32))
        self.img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        image = self.canvas.create_image(5+(pos*32), 5, anchor=NW, image=self.img2)
        list.append(self.image)
        print(list)
        pos+=1

    def ski2(self):
        list.remove(21)
        self.canvas.delete(image)
        print(list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = test(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: При удалении объектов оставшиеся объекты должны передвигаться на холсте? И добавьте код, где вы что-то пытаетесь удалять.

Comment: Да, должны. Ок, добавил но оно топорное, так как номерация вообще непонятно почему начинается с 21, и удаления по нумерации вообще не подходит, ведь я могу далить элемент, а после решу добавить с таким же "именем" и у него то уже будет другой номер

Comment: Удаляйте по индексу в списке, а не по значению. Можно pop использовать, чтобы вытащить элемент из списка, и удалить его из него: `image_to_delete = list.pop(0)`, потом этот же объект удаляете через canvas.delete, а не то что у вас в переменную image последним было записано. P.S. называть переменную list - очень плохая идея.

Comment: @insolor 1- имя `list` пррсто как пример. 2- мне бы желательно как-то удалять по названию переменной, а именно в примере это `image`. Удаление я еще понимаю как реализовать, это поиск сделать по списку и удалять. Меня больше беспокоит не понимания как при добавлении и удалении двигать на холсте эти объекты.

Comment: Даже как пример не нужно.

Comment: "Меня больше беспокоит не понимания как при добавлении и удалении двигать на холсте эти объекты." - ну у вас же в списке id этих объектов, в чем проблема по списку циклом пройти и все объекты подвинуть как нужно.

Comment: По названию переменной не нужно делать, сделайте словарь с именами и id объектов, например. Либо тег вешайте на объект.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а можно наглядный пример, я не понимаю так

Comment: Что именно из перечисленного?

Comment: @insolor цикл по сдвигу на холсте. Ведь у меня даже добавление сейчас не совсем правильное.

Comment: Я понял что мне надо вконце просто в цикле перерисовывать все объекты в списке с новыми значениями, но я не пойму как это сделать через `self.canvas.itemconfigure()`

Comment: Извиняюсь туплю. Есть же `move`